# awk/sed on csv with #text

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am newbie here, so any directions would help. Have a csv file ( comma seprated ) and in one of the columns there is text delimited with # sign ( the column is delimeted by # on it`s own ). Here is an example of a line:

```
text,text devicetype,cidr,text#more text#XXXX|more
text#even more text#more
text#text_toreplace#text|text#text
```

text_toreplace is what i want substitued with different text, without changing all the rest of the data in the column with value "text#more text#XXXX|more text#even more text#more text#text_toreplace#text|text#text"

The CSV does have the first raw as headers and there would be multiple lines after that.

Sample output would be exactly the same with the coumn dlimted by # and one value differance :

```
text,text devicetype,cidr,text#more text#XXXX|more
text#even more text#more
text#REPLACED_TEXT#text|text#text
```

Ideas

Comment: [here is a great sed introduction](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-0) and it's easy to learn regex with [regex crosswords](https://regexcrossword.com/)

Comment: So, the fields have subfields (delimited by `#`)? If you use `awk` you can `split()` the column on `#`, replace what you'd like and concatenate them back together.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Solved with simple sed from the proposed intruction link .

Comment: @Nixe.Kis Please share your solution as answer. So it will be helpful for others. 

Give a man regex solution, he will be happy for a day. Teach him sed and regex happy for life. :P

Comment: @Nixe.Kis it's extremely unlikely that a sed script would be the best solution. Chances are an awk one would be some combination of clearer, more robust, more portable, more efficient, etc. If you [edit] your question to tell us what the criteria is to select which field to update (e.g. specific text and/or on a specific line and/or in a specific field and/or in a specific sub-field and/or occurring a specific number of times, etc.) then we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#` as the "primary" field separator, iterate over the fields to replace the offending text.

```
awk -F'#' -v OFS='#' '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i == "text_toreplace")
            $i = "REPLACED_TEXT"
    print
}' <<'END_INPUT'
text,text devicetype,cidr,text#more text#XXXX|more
text#even more text#more
text#text_toreplace#text|text#text
END_INPUT
```

```
text,text devicetype,cidr,text#more text#XXXX|more
text#even more text#more
text#REPLACED_TEXT#text|text#text
```

Answer (score 0):

with `sed` it will be easier

```
$ sed -E 's/(^|#)(text_toreplace)(#|$)/\1REPLACED_TEXT\3/g' file
```

anchors required to match the first and the last field.